# Best practice for creating a variables page in php?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, permanent

I have to create an administrator control panel and I want to create a php page that just contains variables that can be changed by the administrator and that would affect the rest of the website. Is there a specific best practice method for this? I used the array method below because I saw phpBB (open source forum software) using it. (and of course on my actual website, one php file would create just arrays/array and other php files will contain functions editing the array variables)

```
<?php
$acp_array = array(
    'apple' => 'red',
    'grass' => 'green',
    'sky' => 'blue'
);
print_r($acp_array);

echo '<br />';

$acp_array['sky'] = 'purple';
print_r($acp_array);
?>
```

Also, how would I make the array variable change (in my example the change from blue to purple for the sky variable) permanent? Or is there a better and different way to store php variables that should be used through the site globally?

Comment: i prefer define(), or a db for this

Comment: define('NAME','Anil'); a better way . List all this way . [ I saw in wordpress ]

Comment: Is the usage similar to a configuration array? Then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054613/storing-global-settings-configurable-from-an-admin-page-in-php - but just from the looks I would advise for a data file here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an admin control panel I'd recommend setting up your config key=>val pairs in a database. Easily scalable, and you don't have to worry about setting write permissions to a PHP file.

Example table:

```
Table 'site_config'

| id    | key   | val   |
|_______|_______|_______|
| 1     | apple | red   |
| 2     | grass | green |
| 3     | sky   | blue  |
```

Comment: thanks, I'll be using a db then. for some reason I was under the impressions data base tables weren't supposed to be used for single variable information, lol, i'm basking through the glories of being a self taught web developer haha